testing multiple scripts simultaneously in pine script
I have about 30 different strategies which I've built using pine script and I want to test how they would have performed working concurrently and not just individually.
Is there any way to do this? If not, is there any other program that offers this feature?

You could theoritically do that but there are some limitations you need to be aware of. Some of the important ones:

Execution time limit
Number of request.*() calls
Number of plots/drawings

If we assume everything will be fine after you merge those 30 strategies, you can have an enable/disable input for each strategy.
You write down all the buy and sell conditions for each strategy. The end goal is to and all of them later.
However, if a strategy is disabled, you want it to return true so when you and them later, it will not effect the end results.
Below is an example:
in_strat_1_en = input.bool(false, "Enable Strategy 1")
// Strategy 1 Settings

in_strat_2_en = input.bool(false, "Enable Strategy 2")
// Strategy 2 Settings

strat_1_buy_cond_org = // The original buy condition for Strategy 1
strat_1_buy_cond = in_strat_1_en ? strat_1_buy_cond_org : true          // If strategy 1 is enabled, use the original buy condition. Else, return true to bypass this condition

strat_2_buy_cond_org = // The original buy condition for Strategy 2
strat_2_buy_cond = in_strat_2_en ? strat_2_buy_cond_org : true          // If strategy 2 is enabled, use the original buy condition. Else, return true to bypass this condition

strategy_buy_cond = strat_1_buy_cond and strat_2_buy_cond               // Any disabled strategy will return "true" so that's fine. Any enabled strategy will return its own condition

You need to add one more condition and that is, "if at least one strategy is enabled". Because if all of them are disabled, they all will return true as their buy condition. And then strategy_buy_cond will be true. To prevent this, you need to add another condition where you check if at least one strategy is enabled.
